# Pascal funcs Insert/Delete in Python

Tags: python

Delphi has functions

- `Insert` (insert substring Str2 into string Str at offset P) and
- `Delete` (delete N chars from string Str at offset P).

What is analog of them in Python for strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

- `s1[:p] + s2 + s1[p:]`
- `s1[:p] + s1[p+n:]`

For example:

```
>>> s1 = 'hello world'
>>> s2 = 'xyz'
>>> p = 3
>>> s1[:p] + s2 + s1[p:]
'helxyzlo world'
>>> n = 2
>>> s1[:p] + s1[p+n:]
'hel world'
```

Answer (score 2):

Python strings are immutable, so you can't modify an existing string -- but you *can* apply those operations to a string and produce a new one.

Probably the best way to do it is *slicing*, an extension of the indexing syntax to allow you to pull out multiple characters. So:

```
>>> 'abcde'[1:4]
'bcd'
```

Notice that the first index is inclusive, but the second index is exclusive. That's weird at first, but it's a ubiquitous convention in Python.

If you leave out the first or last index, the slice goes to the beginning or end of the string, respectively:

```
>>> 'abcde'[1:]
'bcde'
>>> 'abcde'[:4]
'abcd'
```

Finally, you can use the `+` operator for string concatenation:

```
>>> 'abc' + 'de'
'abcde'
```

With all these parts together, you can insert and delete substrings as you like:

```
>>> s = 'abcde'
>>> s[:2] + 'XYZ' + s[2:]  # Insert 'XYZ' before index 2
'abXYZcde'
>>> s[:2] + s[4:]          # Delete indices from 2 to before 4
'abe'
```

If you wanted `insert` and `delete` functions as you've described them, you'd be writing them yourself -- but that wouldn't be hard. Spoiler alert -- you may want to give it a try yourself before reading the code below. :)

```
def insert(str, str2, p):
    return str[:p] + str2 + str[p:]

def delete(str, p, n):
    return str[:p] + str[p + n:]
```

(You could probably come up with better argument names -- in particular, using `str` is inadvisable because it's also the name of a Python builtin -- but for this example I've intentionally used the same ones you used in the question.)